# how to prevent gnupg from decrypting files automatically?

Tags: macos, security, terminal, encryption, gnupg

I'm on OSX 10.13.4, I am learning how to use gnupg from the terminal.
I encrypted a file with

`gpg --cipher-algo AES256 -c input.txt -o output.gpg`

it asked me for a password, I made one up, the file is now encrypted. But then, when I issue the command `gpg -d output.gpg` it decrypts it without asking me for the password ?_?

How do I prevent that?

EDIT

Following [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103034/gnupg-decryption-not-asking-for-passphrase/103037#103037) I have set `max-cache-ttl 0` in `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and it seems to work, could anyone confirm that this is indeed the right thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `max-cache-ttl 0` in your `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file does seem to be a good solution. Especially since it works.

There's also the gpg-agent option `--no-allow-external-cache` that's supposed to:

> Tell Pinentry not to enable features which use an external cache for passphrases.
>
> Some  desktop  environments prefer to unlock all credentials with one master pass‐
>                 word and may have installed a Pinentry which employs an additional external  cache
>                 to  implement  such a policy.  By using this option the Pinentry is advised not to
>                 make use of such a cache and  instead  **always  ask  the  user  for  the  requested
>                 passphrase.**

That *sounds* like it should always ask for the passphrase, but it does not appear to do that. Or, it only always asks, when an external cache exists.

Or, you could keep letting gpg-agent cache passphrases, but on demand clear them with by sending a `SIGHUP` signal (with `kill`, `killall`, `pkill`, etc):

> This  signal  flushes  all  cached passphrases and if the program has been started
>                 with a configuration file, the configuration file is  read  again.   Only  certain
>                 options  are  honored: quiet, verbose, debug, debug-all, debug-level, debug-pinen‐
>                 try, no-grab, pinentry-program, pinentry-invisible-char,  default-cache-ttl,  max-
>                 cache-ttl,  ignore-cache-for-signing,  no-allow-external-cache, allow-emacs-pinen‐
>                 try,  no-allow-mark-trusted,   disable-scdaemon,   and   disable-check-own-socket.
>                 scdaemon-program  is  also  supported but due to the current implementation, which
>                 calls the scdaemon only once, it is not of much use unless you manually  kill  the
>                 scdaemon

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to only disable the caching for symmetric encryption/decryption (that don't use public/private keypair). You can do this either with a command line option every time:

```sh
gpg --no-symkey-cache -c input.txt
gpg --no-symkey-cache -d output.gpg
```

Or you can add `no-symkey-cache` to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, then you won't need to add to the command line every time. Note that the `--no-symkey-cache` feature requires `gpg 2.2.7` or later.

This solution is better if you only want to disable the caching for symmetric encryption/decryption that doesn't involve public/private keypairs. It will still cache the passphrases for public/private keypairs.